# How can I implement a version dependent JSONDecoder?

Tags: python, json, decode

I have written a class to decode JSON documents. Now, the code must be able to distinguish between different versions. For this the element 'version' is included on the outermost level.
However, my code processes the elements recusively starting with the deepest nesting.

Is there a simple approach to read the version as the first element and to determine the corresponding decoder based on it?

- version 1.0 -> Decoder1_0
- version 2.0 -> Decoder2_0
- etc.

**JSON File**

```json
{
    "version": 1.0,
    "obj": {
        "subobj": {
            "name": "A",
            "value": 1.2
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

**Python Decoder**

```py
import json
import pathlib
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Subobj:
    name: str
    value: float


@dataclass
class Obj:
    subobj: Subobj


class Decoder1_0(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json.JSONDecoder.__init__(self, object_hook=self.object_hook, *args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def object_hook(obj):
        if 'obj' in obj:
            return ObjectA(**obj)
        elif 'subobj' in obj:
            return Subobj(**obj)
        return obj

input_file = pathlib.Path()  # path to json file

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.load(f, cls=Decoder1_0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install and import [json-stream](https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/), which *streams* JSON as needed, to partially load your JSON document only up to the line containing the version number, so that you can then use the appropriate JSON decoder of yours to actually load the entire document:

```
import json_stream

...

decoders = {
    1.0: Decoder1_0,
    2.0: Decoder2_0
}

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    version = json_stream.load(f)['version']
    f.seek(0)
    data = json.load(f, cls=decoders[version])
```